# USB 3.0 cable to connect laptop with extra monitor

Tags: usb, laptop, multiple-monitors, external-display

I was trying to connect my laptop with an additional monitor to use as an extended display (using the cable shown in the image. I am not quite sure if this can be used for extending display). Upon connecting, the laptop doesn't detect the monitor.

Is this cable for display? Or is there any setting I can change in the laptop to get it corrected?

[cable is shown here with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vsfmh.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cable in the image is an USB 3.0 cable. It can not be used to transmit the display images from a PC to to a regular monitor.

Only USB-C cables with alternate connection mode connected to a special USB-C port on the PC side can be used to connect a monitor with a PC and receive the display content through it.

Alternatively there are active converter cables available (USB-to-HDMI or USB-to-Displayport) that allow to connect a monitor via USB. However these adapters need special drivers that are usually only available for Windows. Note that the USB 3.0 speed is limited and therefore these adapters don't provide the same quality as a simple HDMI or Displayport cable.

Comment: It would be helpful for others to understand what is the purpose of that USB3 cable in the photo. I might be wrong but I think two of those USB3 cables could be used to share TWO computers into ONE monitor. Each computer would be connected to a docking station with that type of USB3 cable. Then ONE cable such as an HDMI cable would go to one monitor. Then with a KVM switch you could display one or the other of the two computers on the one monitor. Hopefully someone will correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @FlexMcMurphy USB3 cables don't have the capability to transmit display signals. Only USB-C cables have the capability to transmit display signals using the USB-C alternate mode.